# How to find the 3 functions(x(t),y(t),z(t)) for this linear integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_C xyz ds$$
I have the following equations: $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ and $x^2+y^2 = \frac{r^2}{4}$.
The first equation represent a sphere and the second equation represents a cylinder.The cylinder is cutting the sphere vertically.
How do you find x(t),y(t) and z(t) based on what I know?

Comment: if $x^2 + y^2 = r^2/4$ then $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2/4 + z^2 = r^2$, so that $z^2 = r^2-r^2/4 = 3/4 * r^2$.

Comment: @tp1 So z(t) is a constant?

Comment: What about the range of domain?